# Throwing away leftover kiddush wine

Tags: grapes-wine, kiddush, kavod, bal-tashchit-waste, holy-objects

In keeping with the general rule that mitzvah objects, including [comestibles](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3235/throwing-out-bread-or-challah), be [discarded respectfully](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15186/1516) (as well as possibly baal tashchis), how should one get rid of leftover kiddush wine? It's not as easy as bread to put into a double-bag and kiss. The first link suggests that even less than a kezayis of bread must be discarded respectfully, so I'm guessing less than a revi'it of kiddush wine must be respected, too. But how? Assume I don't want to drink it now or later.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6936

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, (based on a Gemara) the Kitzur in [סימן עז - דיני הקדוש והסעודות בלילה וביום](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0076_L2) states that one is supposed to leave over wine from the night Kiddush to the morning one, and for the morning for Havdala.

> סעיף ז' 
>   הַכּוֹס צָרִיךְ לִהְיוֹת שָׁלֵם וְנָקִי. וְכָל הַדִּינִים שֶׁהֵן בַּכּוֹס שֶׁל בִּרְכַּת הַמָּזוֹן (לְעֵיל סִימָן מ"ה סָעִיף ג' וְסָעִיף ד') יֵשׁ גַּם בַּכּוֹס שֶׁל קִדּוּשׁ בֵּין בַּיּוֹם בֵּין בַּלַּיְלָה, וְכֵן בַּכּוֹס שֶׁל הַבְדָּלָה. **וְטוֹב לְקַדֵּשׁ בַּלַּיְלָה עַל כּוֹס גָּדוֹל שֶׁיְשַׁיֵּר מִמֶּנּוּ לְקִדּוּשׁ הַיּוֹם וּלְהַבְדָּלָה**. ‏

To answer your question: **One either leaves it in a covered vessel, or one pours it back into the bottle. Either way one has to make sure it is not "Pagum".**

*Pagum*: Wine that is unfit for Kiddush because somebody drank from it already.

*Make sure it is not "Pagum"*: (1) After drinking from it, one adds some wine to the leftovers (and pours it back into the bottle). (2) One doesn't drink from the Kiddush cup; rather one pours some wine into another cup and drinks only from the second cup.

Comment: The question was about how to dispose of it if you don't want it. I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Thanks for this answer. Realistically, do people do this? What if I'm not prepared to pour drunk-from wine back into my wine bottle for future use (nor to ask the kiddush-maker not to drink from the kos shel bracha)?

Comment: @SAH The answer is, yes, people do this. This also relates to the idea of using 'shirayim' from the tish of an Admor. An interesting side question to consider in relation to this is how do you properly handle the wine from Elijah's cup at the conclusion of the seder? And how does this differ from the wine that is poured off for the recital of the plagues?

Comment: @mevaqesh - This was written before the question was edited.

Comment: The only edit to the question doesn't affect my point.